# Issues with Unattended Ubuntu Installl from USB

Tags: usb, unattended-upgrades, kickstart

*****UPDATE: I have now implemented a hack which solves this problem.  I am still looking for help as I don't really consider the hack a solution.  I booted shell (alt+f4) once the computer hung-up on a failure to mount cd-room and typed "tail -n 100 /var/log/syslog" to get a better look at the error.  It said that the device was reported as busy.  This seemed to imply that the install was getting hung up trying to remount the usb it was booting from.  To address this I decided to give it a second usb to find that wouldn't be busy.  So in short I plugged in a second identical usb with the same image and magically this works now.

If anyone has any idea how to actually solve this problem I am still very interested in a more legitimate solution!

Thanks,

-David

***NOTE: this is completely random, but for whatever reason this issue exclusively occurs for me on devices that have not previously had an OS installed.  Once I install an OS, I am able to use a single bootable usb without noteable issues.

---

`

I've been trying to get some hardware (which lacks a CD drive) to work with an unattended install of Ubuntu from a USB. I am trying to use the kickstart method, but it currently returns an error:
   mounting /dev/sda on /media failed: invalid argument

I have the ks.cfg, txt.cfg, and grub.cfg set up as described below.  If you could look them over and let me know what I'm doing wrong, I would very much appreciate it.

grub.cfg:

```
if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
    set gfxmode=auto
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod gfxterm
    terminal_output gfxterm
fi

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

menuentry "Quick Install" {
    set gfxpayload=keep

#THIS IS THE LINE I'M WORRIED ABOUT
    linux   /install/vmlinuz  file=/boot/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed quiet ks=boot:/ks.cfg --


    initrd  /install/initrd.gz
}
menuentry "OEM install (for manufacturers)" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /install/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed quiet oem-config/enable=true --
    initrd  /install/initrd.gz
}
menuentry "Multiple server install with MAAS" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /install/vmlinuz  modules=maas-enlist-udeb vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet --
    initrd  /install/initrd.gz
}
menuentry "Check disc for defects" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /install/vmlinuz  MENU=/bin/cdrom-checker-menu quiet --
    initrd  /install/initrd.gz
}
menuentry "Rescue a broken system" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /install/vmlinuz  rescue/enable=true --
    initrd  /install/initrd.gz
}
```

txt.cfg:

```
default install
label install
  menu label ^Install Ubuntu
  kernel /install/vmlinuz

#THIS IS THE LINE I'M WORRIED ABOUT
  append  file=/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed initrd=/install/initrd.gz ks=boot:/ks.cfg

label cloud
  menu label ^Multiple server install with MAAS
  kernel /install/vmlinuz
  append   modules=maas-enlist-udeb vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet --
label check
  menu label ^Check disc for defects
  kernel /install/vmlinuz
  append   MENU=/bin/cdrom-checker-menu vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet --
label memtest
  menu label Test ^memory
  kernel /install/mt86plus
label hd
  menu label ^Boot from first hard disk
  localboot 0x80
```

and finally my ks.cfg:

```
#Generated by Kickstart Configurator
#platform=x86

#System language
lang en_US
#Language modules to install
langsupport en_US
#System keyboard
keyboard us
#System mouse
mouse
#System timezone
timezone America/New_York
#Root password
rootpw --disabled
#Initial user
user Rattatta --fullname "Rattatta" --iscrypted --password password/
#Reboot after installation
reboot
#Use text mode install
text
#Install OS instead of upgrade
install
#Use CDROM installation media
cdrom
#System bootloader configuration
bootloader --location=mbr 
#Clear the Master Boot Record
zerombr yes
#Partition clearing information
clearpart --all --initlabel 
#Disk partitioning information
part / --fstype ext4 --size 1 --grow 
part swap --recommended 
#System authorization infomation
auth  --useshadow  --enablemd5 
#Network information
network --bootproto=dhcp --device=eth0
#Firewall configuration
firewall --disabled 
#Do not configure the X Window System
skipx
%packages
nano
openssh-server
open-vm-tools --no-install-recommends
```

Thanks very much,

David

Comment: I'm experiencing the same, but without a custom grub.cfg. I've been testing in virtualbox, using my iso as a cdrom but receiving the same error: mounting /dev/sda on /media failed: invalid argument
After this the installation continues, but not unattended. Do you experience the same?
I've tried multiple different values for ks in the line you highlighted, but they all result in the same behaviour. It also seems irrelevant what my ks.cfg contains

Comment: Hi Tobias,
this is exactly what I'm experiencing.

Comment: Hi Tobias,
this is exactly what I'm experiencing. while I have not solved the issue, I have found a work-around that I'm currently employing.  By hosting by ks.cfg on a server and referencing the file from the server I am able to reach an almost unnattended install.  

The line reads "ks=myipaddress:port/ks" (obviously replace port and ip with your own) and I'm using a Flask server which serves the file when a get is made to that address.  You can test this with a simple python server.  Place the ks.cfg in a directory and run "python -m SimpleHTTPServer".  In grub- "ks=youripaddress:port"